# Leaflet 1.0.0-rc3 removeFrom() method causes "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Since upgrading from Leaflet 0.7.7 to 1.0.0-rc3 I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: info.removeFrom is not a function`. The `info` in question is a [control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control) to display some text. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snubian/gnzbss0z/) - the map is displayed and the `info` control added, but the `info.removeFrom(map)` fails with the above error.

If I fork the above JSFiddle and change the Leaflet version back to 0.7.7 then it runs fine ([working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/snubian/24ed702y/)).

I'm fairly new to Leaflet so want to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong, before submitting this as a Leaflet issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, there is a change to the API whereby `removeFrom()` in 0.7.7 becomes `remove()` in 1.0. Wasn't aware of the separate docs for API 1.0. Have made this correction and all is well now.